# pandoc markdown or multimarkdown

Tags: markdown, pandoc, multimarkdown

I am thinking of using an editor like sublime text to write **markdown** files.
Then I could later convert those to HTML, PDF or LaTeX, which would be very convenient for me, as I aim to write fiction and nonfiction (using quotes, bibliographies etc).

Simple Markdown is very limited so I want to use either **pandoc markdown** or **multimarkdown**. As those seem to be the most used or at least most mentioned versions.

When taking stability, support, longevity, ease of use and configurability into account - is there one version that lacks behind severely?

Comment: I may be biased, so see e.g. [Pandoc-vs-Multimarkdown](https://github.com/jgm/pandoc/wiki/Pandoc-vs-Multimarkdown) or [Why I switched from MultiMarkdown to Pandoc](https://dtucker.co.uk/lifehack/why-i-switched-from-multimarkdown-to-pandoc.html)

Comment: thanks, after reading i chose pandoc markdown